# Find 6th derivative of $(\cos(5x^2)-1)/x^2$ at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives

Let 
$$ 
f(x)=\frac{\cos(5x^2)-1}{x^2}
$$
We want to compute the $6th$ derivate of $f(x)$ at $x=0$.

Using a calculator, I found $18750$ (which is correct). But I don't understand how to find this result?

There is an additional hint, which is using the MacLaurin series for $f(x)$. I know I should use the cos Maclaurin series, but I find $0$ as a result.

I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @PdotWang oops! corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the formula by Aaron, we have: 
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n{{(5x^2)^{2n} \cdot x^{-2}} \over {(2n)!}}$$
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n{{(25)^{n}} \over {(2n)!}} \cdot x^{4n-2}$$

For $f^{(6)}$ when $x \to 0$, only this term is concerned when $4n-2=6$, that is $n=2$.

$$f^{(6)}(x)=(-1)^2{{(25)^{2}} \over {(4)!}} 6!=18750$$

Comment: It makes so much sense now! Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

$$\cos (5x^2)  - 1 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{(5x^2)^{2n}}{2n!}$$

Comment: Nice! This makes a lot of sense considering it will generalize everything. Great application of a series I will remember.

Comment: Should be (2n)! This method is good.

Answer (score 0):

First, you define f (x) in two different ways - first you multiply by $x^2$, next you divide by $x^2$. Which one is it?

To solve the problem: Write down the Taylor polynomial for cos x. Substitute $5x^2$ for x, which turns for example $x^6$ into $5^6 x^{12}$. The sixth derivative of $x^n$ is 0 if n<6. It is some constant times $x^{n-6}$ if n > 6 which is 0 when x = 0. And it is 6! when n = 6.

Now the 18,750 that you mention seems to be the sixth derivative of $(\cos 5x - 1)x^2$ at x = 0 which is not quite what you asked.

Comment: Sorry there is a typo in the title. It is divided by x^2. Thanks for your help.